# tornado server : Nameerror global name not defined

Tags: python, html, angularjs, tornado

I am rendering a HTML page from Tornado server:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.render("neo4j-panama_tornado.html")

class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")

    def on_message(self, message):
        #print self
        print message
        message_new = message.split('XXXX') 
        keyword_or_query = message_new[0]
        label_type = message_new[1]
        print keyword_or_query
        print node_id
        self.write_message(node_id)

    def on_close(self):
        pass

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/websocket', WebSocketHandler),
    (r'/(.+)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'web_resources/static/'}),
    (r'/(favicon.ico)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'web_resources/static/img/'}), # TODO: fix favicon (not being found-)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_command_line()
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-cygwin-2.5.1-i686.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1401, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-cygwin-2.5.1-i686.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1603, in wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 120, in get
    self.render("neo4j-panama_tornado.html")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-cygwin-2.5.1-i686.egg/tornado/web.py", line 699, in render
    html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-cygwin-2.5.1-i686.egg/tornado/web.py", line 806, in render_string
    return t.generate(**namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-cygwin-2.5.1-i686.egg/tornado/template.py", line 345, in generate
    return execute()
  File "neo4j-panama_tornado_html.generated.py", line 5, in _tt_execute
    _tt_tmp = var.Name  # neo4j-panama_tornado.html:259
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```

HTML code using AngularJS:

```html
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Search</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Index</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above HTML code works fine when run independently, but I get an error when rendered through Tornado.

Answer (score 0):

Tornado is attempting to render your HTML file as a template; hence it's looking up "var" in the template namespace and doesn't find it. You need to use a static file handler for "/" instead:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/?()", web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'templates',
                                      'default_filename': 'index.html'}),
])
```

The "()" in the URL is a "capture group". The reason for it is a bit subtle, see [the documentation for StaticFileHandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler) and the sentence, "Note that a capture group in the regex is required to parse the value for the path argument to the get() method."

Comment: Isn't :  (r'/(.+)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': 'web_resources/static/'}),  suppose to do that? Can you please tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: Edited my answer to use a StaticFileHandler.